# ImportError: No module named X, even if folder is in the same directory

Tags: python

I've downloaded pymumble from https://github.com/Robert904/pymumble and saved it to my working directory.  I import it with:

```
from pymumble import pymumble
```

However, I receive:

```
ImportError: No module named pymumble
```

I'm looking at similar code that does this successfully.  What am I doing wrong when trying to import this?

Comment: See https://github.com/azlux/pymumble

Comment: have you tried from pymumble import *

Comment: Even "import pymumble" fails, it can't find the directory for some reason, even though it's in the same directory as the script.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see there is no file called pymumble in given repository, if you are looking for this there is a file called mumble.py, try importing

```
from mumble import mumble
```

this will work.

Comment: Doesn't work, it can't find the pymumble directory, so it wouldn't be able to import mumble.py anyway.